# AWS nodejs handler module with dots yields "Bad handler" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to put my event handler function in a file called `app.lambda.js` because the `app.js` should contain only generic stuff not related to AWS Lambda.

But specifying "app.lambda.handler" as a handler yields `Bad handler app.lambda.handler`.

Is it simply impossible to use dots in the file name of the handler module?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you come up with a solution? For now I am replacing all dots by dashes.

Comment: Nope, in the end I just renamed files and changed dots for underscores.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You should give app.handler. Only one dot will allow you in handler name.
Try by giving your filename.handler. It will work for you.